# How to close a Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to generate a window with two buttons, both of which will execute a function and then close the window. However, I can't seem to get the window to close. I've tried rewriting with function several times as per answers to similar questions, but get an error each time. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import tkinter as tk


class test:
    def __init__(self, root):
       self.text = tk.Label(root, text = 'Question' )
       self.text.pack(side = 'top')
       self.button1 = tk.Button(root, text = 'Yes', command = self.write_right, width = 15)
       self.button1.pack(side='left')
       self.button2 = tk.Button(root, text = 'No', command = self.write_wrong, width = 15)
       self.button2.pack(side='right')
    def write_right(self):
        self.root.destroy()
    def write_wrong(self):
        self.root.destroy()
box = tk.Tk()
functionality = test(box)
box.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `self.root = root` can help:

```
import tkinter as tk

class test:
    def __init__(self, root):
       self.root = root
       self.text = tk.Label(root, text = 'Question' )
       self.text.pack(side = 'top')
       self.button1 = tk.Button(root, text = 'Yes', command = self.write_right, width = 15)
       self.button1.pack(side='left')
       self.button2 = tk.Button(root, text = 'No', command = self.write_wrong, width = 15)
       self.button2.pack(side='right')
    def write_right(self):
        self.root.destroy()
    def write_wrong(self):
        self.root.destroy()
box = tk.Tk()
functionality = test(box)
box.mainloop()
```